# Installing emacs on red hat linux 5

Tags: linux, emacs

I am very new to Linux , we are trying to install Emacs editor on linux which is Red hat Linux5.

We setup VMWare and installed linux on that , i tried google a lot and couldn't find any tutorial on how to install emacs on Linux.

I am totally new to linux , can someone explain how to do the same.

It will be of great help thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try `yum install emacs` ?

Comment: wow that command works but it says the following error ftp://192.168.0.5/pub/server/repodata/respond.xml timedout

Comment: and then it said trying other mirror , error: Cannot open /read repomd.xml file for repository:core ,

Comment: to give you more info , i am able to browse on my vm through firefox

Comment: You have to run `yum` as root. Do you have root access?

Comment: yes i only installed that , i am running this command from root only , how can i check that?

Comment: I don't really understand your response, but just try running `sudo yum install emacs` then.

Comment: @jjlin sure , let me try that , one more thing , how do i know that i am running as root , the command line shows root@emicroz

Comment: i did that with sudo command , still same error , after setting up repositories , it says fto timedout error

Comment: i am getting one more error , the system is not registered with RHN

Comment: So is the system registered with RHN? I've heard you need an RHN subscription to even run RHEL, but I'm not familiar with the details, as I just use the RHEL-compatible [CentOS](http://www.centos.org/).

Comment: finally installed Ubunto , this is nice and free

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting `emacs: error while loading shared libraries: libXfixes.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` when starting emacs, do:

```
yum remove emacs
yum install emacs-nox
```

Comment: Isn't the package manager supposed to automatically install all needed libraries when the `emacs` package is installed?

Comment: I dunno; it didn't happen in my case — I first tried doing `yum install emacs` as per the other answer, but that resulted in the error as above being generated when then trying to start the emacs.  I had to install `emacs-nox` and also remove `emacs` in order for `emacs` to work.

Answer (score -1):

If your RH VM hasn't connection to repository you can download rpm package and install it locally. For example:

```
rpm localinstall emacs-21.2-2.i386.rpm
```

Comment: I believe you've confused yum/rpm.